# How to use oauth2.clientcredentials with a non-standard auth token endpoint?

Tags: go, oauth-2.0

oauth2.clientcredentials is brilliant for building a REST client implementation that autorefreshes its token, given the right endpoint. I'm trying to use it with an endpoint that doesn't use the standard signature. The call is a POST that expects:

```
{
    "loginId": "apiClient",
    "apiKey": "F7694C56886933570EE1B03FAC2CD80671E57586"
}
```

in the body and returns something like:

```
{
   "data": {
      "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c",
      "expiresIn": 900
   }
}
```

Nary a "clientId" nor "clientSecret" to be found. I'm struggling to see how I can use the standard implementation in the Go libraries in this context.